# Random selected results of events

Tags: javascript, string, permutation

Please help. I am very new to these things and I am challenged to come up with a solution.

I need a JavaScript code that will help me automatically select at random results of events which has 3 possible outcomes like football - Home, Draw or Away win. And there are a total of 10 events. One result must come out of each event at a time (it could be Home Win (a), Draw (b), or AwayWin(c)) and result or outcome must be randomly selected for the 10 events until there is no other possibilities.  I tried to use recursion and different kinds of string permutation methods in JavaScript but I didn't get it. 
Description of what I want can be viewed from the link above.
 Thanks.

Illustration of what I want:
[image]

Comment: Please use image button in editor to add your image.

Comment: By all the possibilities do you mean `3^10` sequences that are possible? Then you need to create all the permutations first and choose randomly and remove from the set until you are out of permutations.

Comment: Thanks jal_a for the edits and comment. But as regards what you said, I tried your approach but things got too cumbersome and confusing at a point so I stopped and decided to start over with a new approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. I think the comments are clear but let me know if it needs explanation. You can set different number of events and array of outcomes as well.

```
// number of events (length of sequence)
const numEvents = 10;

// possible outcomes
const outcomes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

// total number of possible permutations
// (number of outcomes to the power of number of events)
const numPermutations = outcomes.length**numEvents;

// permutations indices [0, 1, .., numPermutations - 1]
let permutations = Array(numPermutations).fill(0).map((v, i) => i)

// convert sequence of digits to sequence of outcomes ('012' -> 'a b c')
function sequenceToChars(sequence) {
  return Array.from(sequence).map(i => outcomes[i]).join(' ');
}

// convert permutation index to an outcome sequence (2 -> 'a a c')
function permutationToSequence(permutation) {
  // get the sequence as a number in base of number of outcomes
  const sequence = permutation.toString(outcomes.length).padStart(numEvents, '0')
  return sequenceToChars(sequence)
}

// pick a permutation randomly until no permutations left
for (let i = 0; i < numPermutations; i++) {
  // choose a random index of permutations left
  const rand_idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * permutations.length)

  // remove and return chosen index
  permutation = permutations.splice(rand_idx, 1)[0]

  // convert permutation index to sequence
  const sequence = permutationToSequence(permutation)
  console.log(sequence)
}
```

Comment: Thanks jal_a. Exactly what I needed. It works perfectly fine. Studying it, I now know how it works and I can modify it for something else

Answer (score 1):

If you do not *need* to generate all of the possible sequences, you can write a generator function that can produce any single sequence deterministically.

This javascript snippet will generate the first 10 sequences for football games.

You can obtain any single one by doing a single call to `footballGenerator()`

```
// generates a generic sequence
function sequenceGenerator(index, length, radix) {
    return Array.from(
        (index % (length * radix))
            .toString(radix)
            .padStart(length, '0')
        ).map(n => parseInt(n))
}

// convert a generically generated sequence into a football season's outcomes
function footballGenerator(seed, seasonLength) {
    return sequenceGenerator(seed, seasonLength, 3).map(game => {
        if (game == 0) {
            return "Home"
        } else if (game == 1) {
            return "Draw"
        } else {
            return "Away"
        }
    })
}

// example usage of the `footballGenerator()` function
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(footballGenerator(i, 10))
}
```

Comment: Hello Zylviij thanks for the input. But I still have some questions because I need more ellaboration on the code, even though the comments in the code are helpful, as a newbie I still find my self lost 1.  In this case what are index, length and radix? Are they some variables I have to assign values? How so? 2. What is Seed and SeasonLength? 3. How do I call the first set of code (sequence Generator) to generate a generic sequence? Thanks alot.

Comment: I don't see any randomization in the algorithm.